# Weird space below my webpage in safari and chrome only

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I'm getting a blank space at the bottom of my contact page and I can't figure out why. 
It only happens in chrome and safari that i know of.
http://tshirthideout.com/contact-us/

I don't think the problem is in my footer template because its only on the contact page. so here is my code for the content on the page.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>


<div style="position: relative; top: -35px; left: 3px; display: block;margin-bottom: 40px;">

    <div id="ribbon"><span style="padding-left: 11px; color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #c1c1c1,2px 2px 0px #c1c1c1;
        font-size: 30px;font-family:'Century Gothic',futura,'URW Gothic L',Verdana,sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;"><strong><h1 style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 11px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></strong></span></div>
<div style="right: 5px; top: 48px; position: absolute; display: block;"><form class="widget-area" role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />
    </div>
</form></div>
</div>
    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add `Display:block` to the iframe

Answer (score 2):

That space coused by this `<iframe src="about:blank" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; visibility: hidden; border: none;">...</iframe>` element.

Comment: then the form plugin must be using this iframe for what ever reason because i didnt put it there. thnx for pointing it out.